# How to use a regex to find and replace the beginning and end of a string

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I've a lot of strings like this:

```
<string name="minutes">minutes</string>
<string name="hours">hours</string>
<string name="zero_minutes">None</string>
```

I want to get only values:

```
minutes
hours
None
```

I wanted to do a regular expression to find all the ones that start with `<string` and end with `">` and replace with a blank space. How can I do this?

I went through multiple topics of this, but my expressions do not work:

```
com\/\K<string(\/.*?)\">
```

Comment: Do yo mean like this? `</?string\b[^<>]*>` https://regex101.com/r/lrolhX/1 If you want the values, perhaps using a parser would be better.

Comment: Just curious if this would help `>(.+)<` where first captured group would give values you are interested.

Comment: Regular expressions are not good choices to process HTML. While they might work on a single file, if a subsequent file varies in format the patterns become likely to fail, causing your system to break. Instead, learn to use a HTML parser and process the HTML with it. Your system will be much more robust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find

```
<string[^>]*>([^<]*)</string>
```

Replace

```
$1
```

Note that this regex is fragile and will not account for whitespaces (e.g. `< string>`) or carets inside quotes (e.g. `<string name=">">`). It's best to use a parser.